# Are the sets $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ equinumerous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the sets $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$  equinumerous, so is there a bijective function between these sets? And what's the best way to find such a function if it exists?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573794/prove-that-mathbbr-and-the-interval-0-infty-have-the-same-cardinality and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699298/f-mathbb-r-to-0-infty-defined-by-fx-ex-describe-its-inverse

Answer (score 2):

The exponential map $\exp \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is a (continuous) bijection with (continuous) inverse $\log \colon \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$.

You could also use the map
$$ 
 \phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1), \quad x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+|x|}.
$$
This is a bijection with inverse
$$
 \psi \colon (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto \frac{x}{1-|x|}.
$$
Because $\phi$ restricts to a bijection $\phi|_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}} \colon \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to (0,1)$ and
$$
 f \colon (-1,1) \to (0,1), \quad x \mapsto \frac{x+1}{2}
$$
is also a bijection, the composition $\psi|_{(0,1)} \circ f \circ \phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is bijective.